# Jenkins dynamic agent selection

Tags: jenkins, continuous-integration, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy

I have different kinds of agents on my Jenkins controller. Static agents (some virtual machines and some bare metal servers), and dynamic agents (a couple Kubernetes cloud instances). Static agents are labelled as per OS (windows, linux) and dynamic (Kubernetes) can run on different docker images based on the project. No label for these as they could change per OS and docker image.

How can I write a Jenkins pipeline which is selecting agents dynamically at runtime?

I can provide 4 env params while triggering build. `AGENT_TYPE` with possible values are `["static", "dynamic"]` , `AGENT_OS` with possible values as `["linux", "windows"]` , `AGENT_IMAGE` a string value, link of docker image and `AGENT_CLOUD` which has the cloud name of Kubernetes.

If the env param says to use static agents, build starts on those using OS as label, and if Kubernetes is selected it would use other params to gather Kubernetes configs.

I am struggling to write a pipeline that chooses between `label` and `kubernetes` in `agent` section of a Jenkins pipeline. Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

First you can use something like this:

```
def agent_label = 'dev-agent'
agent any
parameters {}

environment 
{  }

stages
{
  stage('prepare-code') {
    steps {
      script {
        // choose agent based on environment to run
        if (environment != "dev")
        {
          agent_label = 'prod-agent'
        }
      }
    }
  }

  stage('deploy') {
    agent {
      label agent_label
    }
    steps { .....
```

You can also use the jenkin's worker tags, and give a couple of agents the same tag, and then have a group of agents under the same agent tag, which is great for scaling the loads